# JavaScript: get scrollY position of searched text on body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need `scrollY` position of searched text. How to find text in body and get `scrollY`  position of the found text.

Following code is an example about question:
(all is clear)

```
<script>
    function getScrollYPosition(var str){
        /* step 1: search str in <body> and found.
         * step 2: get scrollY position of found str.
         * step 3: return position. (500)
         */
    }
</script>

<body>
    <p>Hello world</p> /*For example scrollY position is 500*/
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide some code, it is hard to assist you without code!

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to find the position of the highlighted text when searched by the browser or do you have a custom way of searching ?

Comment: like browser searching but I need to only scrollY position of found text

Comment: So you want the position of the text which is highlighted. In that scenario since there are many many many browsers and no API (derp) the only way you can achieve that is by letting the search finish and listen to scrollY changes when the document is not focussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first match the text string,
wrap it into an (`span`) element
and than calculate that element offset position

Here's a quick example

```js
var word = 'dolor';
var rgx = new RegExp('\\b('+word+')\\b', 'ig');

// CREATE SPAN ELEMENTS WHAT WILL WRAP THE QUERY STRING (WORD)
$('div, div *').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).text().replace(rgx, "<span class='match'>$1</span>"));
});

// COLLECT ALL SPAN POSITIONS
var positions = $('.match').map(function(){
  return this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
}).get();

alert(positions);
```

```css
div{font-size:50px;}
span.match{background: gold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut voluptatum, provident saepe. Culpa animi sint, itaque iure error hic qui blanditiis perspiciatis adipisci, libero quia veritatis dignissimos quasi id cumque!</div>
<div>Magni cupiditate laudantium, corrupti commodi, reiciendis consequuntur recusandae minima tempore id placeat rerum saepe molestiae, nulla illo, dolores distinctio aliquid asperiores esse maxime voluptatibus corporis at. Commodi eius magni esse!</div>
<div>Maiores explicabo, dolor nemo mollitia cumque et nobis quae consectetur alias dicta quod facere saepe aspernatur sint ex soluta nulla veritatis ab. Sunt aspernatur distinctio quam alias quis possimus reiciendis impedit.</div>
<div>Est sequi eius nam, odio ut commodi quam omnis aperiam, vel, sunt quaerat adipisci voluptates natus possimus consequuntur corporis atque facere corrupti, rem autem modi ipsam inventore nobis! Itaque, modi?</div>
<div>Velit, cumque in dicta ratione iste autem, atque dolor magni optio, excepturi qui ipsam laboriosam modi quidem cupiditate sapiente perferendis! Iste eos fuga ut eum deserunt repellendus ex qui, illo eaque!</div>
<div>Ullam a, labore aperiam ex culpa nesciunt ipsam voluptatibus maiores consequatur qui repellendus obcaecati tenetur, consectetur eos, ut voluptate, nemo placeat soluta odit? Error, Dolor, voluptatibus! Id sed alias et consectetur.</div>
<div>Ipsa pariatur tenetur, nobis recusandae deserunt quisquam nesciunt, ex consequuntur minus voluptatem dolores officiis itaque fuga reiciendis dolor praesentium quae maxime repudiandae. Quibusdam sint fugit soluta pariatur, alias, eveniet natus culpa!</div>
```

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @ATES here you go! The resulting array shows all the positions of the desired word.

Comment: very clear, awesome thank you so much.

Comment: @ATES thx! you're welcome!

Comment: There are a small problem. It does not support Unicode characters such as "ıİ,üÜ,ğĞ,Öö,çÇ,şŞ". Are there any solution?

Comment: @ATES works for me: http://jsbin.com/dimiro/1/edit?html,css,js,output , you need eventually to translate your character entities first https://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html

Answer (score 1):

You could be a little more specific with your answer. If I understand correctly you need to find an element that contains a given text and get its vertical offset. You could try the following:

```
$($(":contains(YOUR_TEXT)").slice(-1)[0]).offset().top
```

Comment: that will give the position of an element containing some text, even if that specific text is positioned at the far bottom of that element... Not clear from the Q what's exactly OP's desire though...